Is it common for a Standing Seam Roof to have Exposed Fasteners?
I don't know anything about roofs but I hired a roofer to install a standing seam metal roof and the side wall flashing has exposed fasteners. Is having hidden fasteners on the flashing something I needed to specify in the beginning? Or is it common to have exposed fasteners to hold down the sidewall flashing?  Below is a photo of some of the flashing screwed into the metal panels.


Pics, help here. otherwise we are guessing about what you have .

Thanks! I added a photo : )

The fasteners in question are common for that type of roofing.
